# GIT push error Missing or invalid credentials

Tags: git

HELP!!!! this is a new error for me.  i have done git pushes before with no issues.  but today, i got this error when doing a push.

Missing or invalid credentials.

```
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:559:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:433:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1168:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

Comment: Please provide full traceback.

Comment: Are you using VSCode? Try running this script on a terminal outside VSCode

Comment: And the command that caused the failure

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue but this was after the 2fa authentication my solution was use other terminal outside vscode and this prompted to enter the user name and password, where the password was the access token